# How to know which output function to use

Tags: neural-networks, linear-model

To design a Neural network for binary classification, We use a single neuron
How to know which output function to apply in that neuron?
i.e. Linear threshold or Sigmoid?

Answer (score 0):

'Output' function? You mean [activation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_function)! It depends on your specific case. And why do you want to change it in the first place? Stick with Sigmoid until you figure out you need something else!

**PS:** why are you only interested in changing the activation function of the output neurons? (vs. hidden neurons as well)

Comment: It's a binary classifier so don't need hidden layers :) , I am assuming a single neuron would be sufficient looking at the data! but would adding hidden units improve accuracy?

Comment: Just because it's a binary classifier does not mean you don't need hidden layers. If your set looks like [this](https://www.otexts.org/sites/default/files/resize/sfml/images/discrilin-600x599.png) it might not. But for more complex cases, like the [XOR](http://www.ece.utep.edu/research/webfuzzy/docs/kk-thesis/kk-thesis-html/img43.gif) you're gonna need hidden neurons.